# How to style table as responsive using Jquery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How to style table as responsive using Jquery mobile?

Currently I am customizing a jquery mobile theme for magento. But the tables are not responsive. When the mobile screens comes too small,horizontal scrolling comes.

I added a css from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/tables/docs/tables/table-reflow.html) along with jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css.

```
.ui-table {
   border: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
.ui-table th,
.ui-table td {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .4em .5em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.ui-table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-table caption {
  text-align:left;
  margin-bottom:1.4em;
  opacity:50%;
}

/* Add strokes between each row */
.table-stroke thead th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6; /* non-RGBA fallback */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.table-stroke tbody th,
.table-stroke tbody td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6; /* non-RGBA fallback  */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}


/* Add alternating row stripes */
.table-stripe tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
.table-stripe tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #eeeeee; /* non-RGBA fallback  */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
/* Add stroke to the header and last item */
.table-stripe thead th,
.table-stripe tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6; /* non-RGBA fallback  */
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

But still it doesnt work.  My CSS and JS are,

1. jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css
2. jquery-1.6.2.min.js
3. jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js

Am I missing something?

Comment: Tak a look here: http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/. It is not only about styling, a little more work should be done here, too...

Comment: Sorry.. Styles out side jquery mobile is not allowed in this project... :(

Comment: Responsive design is not about jQuery or jQuery mobile, so read the article, look for other solutions (like that from [Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) - his solution is only about CSS!). Don't wait that somebody will write the whole solution for You here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the [Responsive Tables](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/tables/index.html) and [Responsive Grids](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/demos/grids/rwd-basics.html) slated for JQM 1.3 release.

Answer (score 1):

There's already an active jQM plugin for responsive table view, you can find it here: https://github.com/frequent/tableview

Demo can be found here: http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/tableview/demo.html

If you need more info you can always ask an developer, he is an active member of this community: https://stackoverflow.com/users/536768/frequent

**WARNING:**

This implementation requires two additional js files + one CSS.